# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-props

I have an product.js file. I want to read data by id like http://localhost:3000/product/2 (/product/:id). But its show me TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined react.
I just want to read my product by product id. I read my all products. But when I want to read single data its show this error. I think its props problem. Please help me out.
I give my file.
my **product.js** file.

```
exports.products = [
  {
    _id: '1',
    name: 'Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones',
    image: '/images/airpods.jpg',
    description:
      'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 89.99,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    name: 'iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory',
    image: '/images/phone.jpg',
    description:
      'Introducing the iPhone 11 Pro. A transformative triple-camera system that adds tons of capability without complexity. An unprecedented leap in battery life',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 599.99,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 4.0,
    numReviews: 8,
  },
  {
    _id: '3',
    name: 'Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera',
    image: '/images/camera.jpg',
    description:
      'Characterized by versatile imaging specs, the Canon EOS 80D further clarifies itself using a pair of robust focusing systems and an intuitive design',
    brand: 'Cannon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 929.99,
    countInStock: 5,
    rating: 3,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '4',
    name: 'Sony Playstation 4 Pro White Version',
    image: '/images/playstation.jpg',
    description:
      'The ultimate home entertainment center starts with PlayStation. Whether you are into gaming, HD movies, television, music',
    brand: 'Sony',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 399.99,
    countInStock: 11,
    rating: 5,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '5',
    name: 'Logitech G-Series Gaming Mouse',
    image: '/images/mouse.jpg',
    description:
      'Get a better handle on your games with this Logitech LIGHTSYNC gaming mouse. The six programmable buttons allow customization for a smooth playing experience',
    brand: 'Logitech',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 49.99,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 3.5,
    numReviews: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: '6',
    name: 'Amazon Echo Dot 3rd Generation',
    image: '/images/alexa.jpg',
    description:
      'Meet Echo Dot - Our most popular smart speaker with a fabric design. It is our most compact smart speaker that fits perfectly into small space',
    brand: 'Amazon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 29.99,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 4,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
]

// export default products;
```

My **App,js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Nav from './components/home/Nav';
import Footer from './components/home/Footer';
import Single from './components/home/Single';
// import AdminHome from './components/admin/AdminHome';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
    <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route  exact  path="/"><Home /></Route>
          <Route    path="/product/:id"><Single /></Route>

        </Switch>
    <Footer/>
    </div>
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My **Single.js**

```
import React, { Component,useState ,useEffect }from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import {products} from "../../products"
const Single = ( match ) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id)

    return (
        <div>

            {product.name}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Single
```

how can i use my props?
So how can i read my single data by ID.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `useParams` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React, { Component,useState ,useEffect }from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import {products} from "../../products"
import {
  
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
const Single = ( match ) => {
      let { id } = useParams();
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === id)

    return (
        <div>

            {product.name}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Single
```

See [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Answer (score 0):

In Single.js, you should either take in `props` as an argument, or destructure it if you want to use `match` directly.

If you're not getting props, you can use `withRouter()` HOC for Single.

Example (I've destructured it to get the id):

```
...
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
...

 const Single = ({
  match: {
    params: { id }
  }
}) => {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === id);
  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};

export default withRouter(Single);
```

[Here's a working CodeSandBox replica for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-worker-fmwwl?file=/src/Single.js:176-401)